# How to make windows program to send sms via android mobile?

Tags: android, .net, vb.net, winforms, winapp

I have to make a .net **Windows application** through which i can send sms through An android mobile connected via Usb. Is there any code or api similar to send sms Like AT Commands in Nokia Mobile.
 I have to send texts through phone. i.e. phone must be connected via usb while sending message.

Comment: Does it Have to send texts though the phone or does the app just need to send texts?

Comment: It have to send texts through phone. i.e. phone must be connected via usb while sending message.

Comment: Ok I guess I can't help then. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

well how long is a piece of string? There are many ways to do this, personally my approach would be to use TCP on VB.Net and make an android app that uses TCP as well. The VB.Net side can then push data to the android phone via the app and the app can send the sms, you could also send any incoming sms to the VB.Net app as well this way and as a bonus, you wouldnt need a cable if they are both connected to the same network (or both have external IP address's, like your home internet and the android had a 3G sim card).

Comment: I am using AT commands in Nokia mobile to send sms via vb.net code, but want to send sms using Android phone. I can not make program for android mobile, i have to make windows application.

Comment: @user3542539 then i would recommend looking up on how to use the gsm modem of the android phone directly.